# Tengo el siguiente código pero al ejecutar la aplicación el segundo onCreate no funciona

Tags: java, eclipse

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ingresar);
    }
    protected void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RelativeLayout layout1=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        Lienzo fondo=new Lienzo(this);
        layout1.addView(fondo);
```

Comment: pero, donde lo llamas para que se ejecute? El método onCreate se ejecuta cuando se crea la actividad pero el método onCreate1 es tuyo y no se invoca automáticamente, tienes que llamarlo tú

Comment: Debes mejorar tu pregunta... Primero la clase que contiene esta función hereda de una clase, la cual tiene un metodo onCreate, segundo el metodo onCreate1 tiene mas implementación que onCreate y no explicas nada...

Answer (score 0):

Nunca llamas a onCreate1. OnCreate se ejecuta porque hereda de tu clase padre, pero onCreate1 ha sido un metodo creado por ti, y no lo llamas en ningún sitio. Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.ingresar);
            onCreate1();
        }
        protected void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            RelativeLayout layout1=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
            Lienzo fondo=new Lienzo(this);
            layout1.addView(fondo);
    }
```